# How can I use setDefaultMemberPermissions for only certain subcommands discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am using the discord.js module for javascript, and am creating a /roles command. Within this /roles command, I have 4 subcommands, create, delete, add, and remove. I am planning to add a list subcommand as well, but there is one issue, which is that I used setDefaultMemberPermissions() on the SlashCommandBuilder, but I only want to set those for the first 4 subcommands, not the list subcommand. Do I need to create a new command or is there a different way to do this?

This is my code right now.
`

```
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
} = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("roles")
    .setDescription("Manage roles for your guild!")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageRoles)
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("create")
        .setDescription("Create a role")
        .addStringOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("name")
            .setDescription("Name of the role you want to add")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("color")
            .setDescription("Set a color for your role")
            .addChoices(
              { name: "RED", value: "RED" },
              { name: "BLUE", value: "BLUE" },
              { name: "GREEN", value: "GREEN" },
              { name: "YELLOW", value: "YELLOW" },
              { name: "PURPLE", value: "PURPLE" },
              { name: "GREY", value: "GREY" }
            )
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("mentionable")
            .setDescription("Enter whether this role should be mentionable")
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("send_messages")
            .setDescription(
              "Enter whether members of this role can send messages"
            )
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("add_reactions")
            .setDescription(
              "Enter whether members of this role can add reactions"
            )
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("attach_files")
            .setDescription(
              "Enter whether members of this role can attach files"
            )
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("connect")
            .setDescription(
              "Enter whether members of this role can connect to vc"
            )
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("change_nickname")
            .setDescription(
              "Enter whether members of this role can change their nickname"
            )
        )
        .addBooleanOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("administrator")
            .setDescription("Enter whether this role should have administrator")
        )
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("delete")
        .setDescription("Delete a role")
        .addRoleOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("role")
            .setDescription("Enter the name of the role you want to delete")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("add")
        .setDescription("Add a role to a user")
        .addRoleOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("role")
            .setDescription("Enter the name of the role you want to add")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addUserOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("user")
            .setDescription("Enter the user you want to add")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("remove")
        .setDescription("Remove a role from a user")
        .addRoleOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("role")
            .setDescription("Role to remove from user")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addUserOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("user")
            .setDescription("Enter the user you want to remove")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    ),
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You cant setDefaultMemberPermissions() for subcommands, but instead Im using

```js
if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
  await interaction.reply({
    content: `You cant use this command`,
    ephemeral: true
  })
} else {
  // your command
}
```

Make sure you have `const {PermissionsBitField} = require('discord.js)` at the top of your command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).